# I need to add a '$' to my output of denominations used

Tags: python

http://ideone.com/QxPDFh

This is my program that I am working on but I need the `amount_denom` to display the $ with the number. How would I get this done? I need to fix the print statement but how? I am new to coding so sometimes I can't see the obvious stuff. Thank you.

```
def main():

    denominations = [20, 10, 5, 1, .25, .10, .05, .01]
    used_denom = []
    amount_denom = []

    user_input = float(input('enter a dollar amount: '))

#Keep asking user to re-enter input until they enter a value (0-200)
    while user_input < 0 or user_input > 200:
        user_input = float(input('re-enter a dollar amount: '))

#Traverse the list to breakdown the user_input into denominations. 
    remainder = user_input
    for d in denominations:
        num_denom = int(remainder / d)

        if num_denom > 0:

            used_denom.append(d)

            amount_denom.append(num_denom)

#Avoid dividing by a float (prevents .01 issue from occurring)
        remainder = (remainder*100) % (d * 100) / 100

#Traverse the amount_denom list and print the output to be formatted a certain way. 
    for i in range(len(amount_denom)):

        print("{0: 2d}{1:8.2f}".format(amount_denom[i],used_denom[i]),end = "")
        print("s" if amount_denom[i] > 1 else "")


main() 

print("{0: 2d}  ${1:8.2f}".format(amount_denom[i],used_denom[i]),end="")
```

this just shows me:
https://gyazo.com/ff41f5c82567c71cca05340f23a51e98

Found out that I just need to change the 8.2f to 5.2f to join the $ and the used_denom to the format I like. Thanks.

Comment: If I input 25: the output needs to show 1 $20 1 $5 for example.

Comment: Have you tried putting a `$` in the format string?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a `$` to your `print` statement?

```
print("${0: 2d}{1:8.2f}".format(amount_denom[i],used_denom[i]),end = "")
```

or:

```
print("{0: 2d} ${1:8.2f}".format(amount_denom[i],used_denom[i]),end = "")
```

You can place the `$` wherever you wish within the string.  You can also add any other characters (e.g. `_` or `-`) within the string.

to remove white spaces around the variables, use `strip()`:

```
print("{0: 2d} ${1:8.2f}".format(amount_denom[i].strip(),used_denom[i].strip()),end = "")
```

if `amount_denom` and `used_denom` are not strings, first convert using `str()`:

```
print("{0: 2d} ${1:8.2f}".format(str(amount_denom[i]).strip(),str(used_denom[i]).strip()),end = "")
```

Comment: It puts it in the wrong place. I need the $ to go only in front of used_denom.

Comment: It puts the $ after the amount_denom but directly after then has a space before used_denom. I need it to have amount_denom 'space' then $used_denom

Comment: Add a space just before the $ sign. Essentially, you can format the string however you wish, and the {} brackets will place whatever variable. Make sense?

Comment: Use `strip()` to remove the white spaces on either side of `amount_denom` and `used_denom`.  see updated answer.